# Azure DevOps - Office Integration Error: TF84033

Tags: windows-10, office365, azure, team-foundation-server

I am attempting to use Excel to refresh and publish items to Azure DevOps but am continously having the same error message appear "

> TF84033: Unable to modify the list.  It is likely that this is caused by data in the worksheet that cannot be moved.  Correct the problem and try again.

[image: Excel Error]

Interestingly enough, this is on a new laptop with a different version of Windows 10 and Office365 installed.  My old laptop works with no errors.  See below for differences in software:

#### New Laptop

```
OS:  
  Edition:  Windows 10 Enterprise  
  Version:  1809  
  OS Build:  17763.134  
Office 365 ProPlus (Version 16.0.10228.20072)  
Team Foundation Server Office Integration 2017 Update 9 (Version 15.129.28308.1)
```

#### Old Laptop:

(no errors when using Excel to update DevOps)

```
OS:  
  Edition:  Windows 10 Enterprise  
  Version:  1607  
  OS Build:  14393.2485  
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 (Version 16.0.4266.1001)  
Team Foundation Server Office Integration 2017 (Version 15.123.27129.2)
```

I understand that the Office Integration tool is not the same version but I can't afford to update it on my old laptop as it's the only way to refresh DevOps, which involves 50% of my job functions.

Answer (score 0):

After updating Office365 to a newer version and rebooting, I opened excel only to find that the Team Foundation Add-in would continuously be disabled.  No amount of enabling it from registry editor nor the Add-ins section of Excel would automatically enable it.

Instead of having to take the time to enable it each time, I went ahead and installed Team Foundation Server office Integration 2019 RC and uninstalled 2017.  After a reboot, I started Excel back up and not only was I able to see the Team tab in the ribbon, I was able to refresh the query without getting an error message.